# GMSMarker show custom uiview as a maker

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

want to show this kind on pin on google map, how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

**From the Documentation:**

Change the default marker icon

> If you want to change the default marker image you can set a custom
>   icon. Custom icons are always set as a UIImage object. The following
>   snippet creates a marker with a custom icon centered at London,
>   England. The snippet assumes that your application contains an image
>   named "house.png".

For [more:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#introduction)

**OBJECTIVE-C**

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5, -0.127);
GMSMarker *london = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
london.title = @"London";
london.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"house"];
london.map = mapView_;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar for selected and unselected markers.   But the idea is still the same with what you want to do.

Assuming you have a parkingObject model, when plotting the markers:

```
-(void) plotMarkers{
    for (ParkingObject *parkingMarker in parkingArray){
        GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];

        marker.position = parkingMarker.position;

        marker.userData = parkingMarker;
        marker.icon = [self createMarker:marker withImageName:@"markerIcon.png"];
        marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake (0.5, 1);
        marker.map = mapView_;
    }
}
```

create custom marker with a different image and data:

```
- (UIImage*) createMarker: (GMSMarker* )marker withImageName:(NSString* )imageName{

    ParkingObject *parkingObject = marker.userData;

    if([imageName isEqualToString:@"markerSelected.png"]){
        MarkerSelected * infoWindow = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"MarkerSelected" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
        infoWindow.markerImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        return [self imageFromView:infoWindow];
    }
    else{
        Marker * infoWindow = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"Marker" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
        infoWindow.priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.0f",parkingObject.rate.floatValue];
        infoWindow.markerImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        return [self imageFromView:infoWindow];
    }
}
```

You'll need to create a marker.xib that has the images/icon/text properties that you can set

this is just sample code, you'll need to customize it for your needs.